# Calling n times the same observable

Tags: rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have a http get webservice which I need to call *n* times, adding the return of my last call each time (first time there is a default value) how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'expand' operator from rxjs. It will loop until it's supplied with empty() observable. Here is example:

```
import { empty } from 'rxjs';
private service; <--- service that gives us the observable by some value
private initialValue: number = 5;
private counter: number = 0;
private source$: Observable<number> = this.service.getSourceWithValue(initialValue);

source$.pipe(
   expand(value => isCounterExceeded()
                   ? incrementCounterAndGetNextSourceObservableWithValue(value);
                   : empty()
   );
// if counter is not exceeded we will increment the counter and create another
// observable based on current value. If it is exceeded, we are stopping the loop by 
// returning the empty() observable

private incrementCounterAndGetNextSourceObservableWithValue(value: number): Observable<number> {
    this.counter++;
    return this.service.getSourceWithValue(value);
}

private isCounterExceeded() {
   return this.counter >= 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you could use `expand`:

```
const N = 4;

const source = of(1).pipe(
  expand((previous, index) => index === 4 ? EMPTY : of(previous * 2))
);

source.subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fcpin2

Comment: I can't change the parameters of my request with that, it just calls *n* times the same request

Comment: So you want to take the result of the last call and use it for the next call?

Comment: Yes exactly I need it to pass it as a parameter for my next http request